# About Pointers and arrays in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I would like to ask a question about pointers and arrays in C++.

```
int a[10];

int *p1; p1 = &a[0];

int *p2; p2 = a;

int (*p3)[10]; p3 = &a;
```

What are the differences between p1, p2 and p3?
They are very confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, `a` is an array of 10 `int`s. That's the easy part.

`p1` is an "pointer to `int`". You are assigning to it the value of `&a[0]`. This takes the address of the first element of `a`. So `p1` now points to the first element of `a`.

`p2` is also an "pointer to `int`". You are assigning `a` directly to it. In this case, a standard conversion must take place called array-to-pointer conversion. Basically, an array can be converted to a pointer to its first element. You are assigning the result of this conversion to `p2`. So `p2` is *also* a pointer to the first element of `a`.

`p3` is a "pointer to array of 10 `int`". You are taking the address of the array `a` and assigning it to this pointer. So now this pointer points at the array itself (not the first element of it).

You might think "well the first element has the same address as the array, so what's the difference?" In fact, you'll notice the difference when you try to increment the pointer. Incrementing either `p1` or `p2` will give you a pointer to the second element of the array. Incrementing `p3` will give you a pointer to the next array of 10 `int`s (which doesn't actually exist).

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ 
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
   ^
   └── p1, p2, p3
```

So if you start off with the all pointing as you have described and then increment them, you get:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬┄
│ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ 
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴┄
         ^                                                     ^
         └── p1, p2                                            └── p3
```

Comment: And while it doesn't exist, it is valid to increment `p3` once, so checking the address difference for yourself after incrementing it is ok and won't invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hah, I love the diagrams :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Your explanation is in detailed and the diagrams are coooool!

Answer (score 5):

`p1` points to the first element of `a`.

`p2` causes `a` to decay into a pointer to the first element, so it also points to the first element of `a`.

`p3` is read as a pointer to an array of ten integers. It points to `a` itself, and incrementing it will move it ahead by `sizeof(int) * 10` instead of `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between these pointer declarations. All of them are pointing to the first element of the array **a[]** (index 0).They are only different styles of writing a statement.